# What is the equivalent of xdebug_break() for Zend Debugger?

Tags: php, zend-debugger

What is the equivalent of `xdebug_break()` for Zend Debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `xdebug_break()` for Zend Debugger is `debugger_start_debug()`.

(see [Zend documentation](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/zendserverapi/zend_debugger-php_api.htm?Highlight=debugger_start_debug))